# Brace initialization and custom constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The following struct

```
template<typename T, int rows, int cols>
struct ScalarCustomType
{
  T data[rows][cols];
}
```

works fine in combination with brace initialization, e.g.,

```
ScalarCustomType<int,3,3> B{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}};
```

as well as

```
ScalarCustomType<int,3,3> B{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

when compiled with c++11/14 support in g++ and clang++. The latter, however, warns about missing braces in the second case.

The library where this struct will be used requires the presence of the custom constructor

```
ScalarCustomType(const T& x) : { ... }
```

which is called in the following manner

```
ScalarCustmType<double,3,3> A(0) // not A{0} !!!
```

How can I reimplement the default brace initializer which gets deleted by the custom constructor?

Thanking you in advance and best wishes,
Matthias

Comment: "*How can I reimplement the default brace initializer which gets deleted by the custom constructor?*" That 'default brace initializer' is aggregate-initialization, and your type ceases to be an aggregate once you add a custom constructor...

Comment: Thanks very much. Can I turn the type back into an aggregate by deriving it from a base class which implements the custom constructor?

Comment: No, such a class won't be [an aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: If you define a custom constructor, the default constructor will not be generated by the compiler, but you can reinforce that by defining `ScalarCustomType() = default;`.

Comment: I know that. The same works for the copy and move constructor which I can reinforce in that way. What I actually wanted to know is if it is possible to explicitly implement a constructor that will accept B{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}}

Comment: @MatthiasMöller : You could have a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>`.

Comment: @MatthiasMöller : See [this demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XfkDehgA1PQwkdko) for some code to get started with.